# how to use asyncio to read Json files from s3?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous, amazon-s3, python-asyncio

All. i have the following code that reads and return some values form JSON files in s3. this code uses multi-threads. my question is how to modify it to use asyncio instead

```
def get_keys_from_prefix(bucket, prefix):
    """
    function to get key from S3 and return a list of keys
    """
    keys_list = []
    paginator = s3.meta.client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix):
        keys = [content['Key'] for content in page.get('Contents')]
        for obj in keys:
            if obj.endswith('.json'):
                keys_list.append(obj)
    return keys_list

def read_json_file_from_s3(bucket, key):
    """
    function to read content of Json file and print location
    """
    try:
        obj = boto3.client('s3').get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        data = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        json_content = json.loads(data)
        Info = json_content['info']
        location = Info.get("location")
        print (key)
        print (location)
    except:
        pass
def multithreading ():
    bucket = "bucket-name"
    prefix = "prefix"
    start = time.perf_counter()

    key_list = get_keys_from_prefix(bucket, prefix)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(read_json_file_from_s3, repeat(bucket), key_list)
        executor.shutdown(wait=True)

    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Finished in {round(finish - start, 2)} second(s)')

multithreading ()
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please show your attempt at solving the problem yourself, and we will help you with issues you encounter.

Answer (score 1):

boto3 client uses blocking functions. If you want to use it with asyncio module you can do it using ThreadPoolExecutor.

For example:

```py
# blocking function
def test():
    time.sleep()
    return 10

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, test)

asyncio.run(main())
```